# Implicit Linking and FreeLibrary in C#

Tags: c#, dll, linker, implicit

I just found out I could unload DLL which is implicit linking with the function FreeLibrary() in C#. I remember I couldn't do this in C++, but it works well in my simple test project. I wonder if this would be okay in my real projects too. **Is it safe to use this method?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fairly vague, I'll have to assume you talk about DLLs that got loaded through pinvoke.  Yes, there is no protection against calling FreeLibrary() twice.  Works in C++ as well btw for a DLL that's loaded explicitly.  Not for implicitly loaded DLLs, they get a reference count of "infinity".

The pinvoke marshaller uses LoadLibrary() under the hood, happens when the very first [DllImport] function gets executed.  The OS loader simply keeps a reference count, every LoadLibrary() call increments it and FreeLibrary() decrements.  When it reaches 0 then it gets unloaded.  So if you pinvoke LoadLibrary() yourself and call FreeLibrary() twice then the DLL *does* get unloaded.  The virtual address space formerly used by the memory-mapped file that maps the code in the DLL is released and can be used again by subsequent allocations.

Safe, no, that's not a word that jumps to mind.  When you accidentally call an entrypoint in the DLL then your program is going to behave very poorly.    The pinvoke marshaller cannot do anything about it, the stub for the native method was already generated.  Odds for an AccessViolationException are decent but not guaranteed.  Arbitrary code execution is technically possible.

The only truly safe way to do this is to ensure that the AppDomain that contains the pinvoke code is unloaded.  You get no help with this, just a rule you have to implement yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply.
But what I meant was about Implicit linking while you're talking about explicit linking. In C++, FreeLibrary() only works properly on Explicit linking linked with the function LoadLibrary(). On the other hand, FreeLibrary() works on both Explicit and Implicit linking in C#. I tested this several times and wanted to make sure calling FreeLibrary() for Implicit linking might not cause any problem in the future because I couldn't find any document about this.
Anyways, thanks for your informative advice!

Comment: It isn't different, in C++ you can still call LoadLibrary() once and FreeLibrary() twice to unload an implicitly loaded DLL.  How the DLL got implicitly loaded in a C# program is not clear from your question at all.  Do improve it please.  And do keep in mind that .NET assemblies are not loaded by LoadLibrary or implicit linking and can only be unloaded by destroying the AppDomain.

Comment: 'Calling LoadLibrary() once and FreeLibrary() twice' in C++ worked for you? I tried that already, called FreeLibrary() more than ten times but it didn't work for DLL loaded using '#pragma comment(lib, "myDLL")'. I'll try that anyways. In C#, I used DllImport attribute to load my own DLL but problem was, there was no way to unload for this method. I searched for how to unload but many guys said just use LoadLibrary() and FreeLibrary() but not DllImport. Frankly speaking, I saw one guy said calling LoadLibrary() once and FreeLibrary() twice in C# just like you.

Comment: But that was only one, so I couldn't be sure if it was okay to use that method just because it works.

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right, implicitly loaded unmanaged DLLs do get a reference count of -1.  A [DllImport] DLL never gets implicitly loaded, the pinvoke marshaller calls LoadLibrary() under the hood.